# Optimization fence problem with twist.

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose you have a 10x15 foot dog house and you wish to build a fence in a yard in a L shape to the north and east of the dog house. If you have 75 feet of fencing material available, what dimensions should the sides of the yard be to maximize the amount of area for the yard?

[image: pic]

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/sedaFBk.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you figure out how much fence is in the other two sides from $w,h$?  This becomes an equation linking $w,h$.  What is the area?

Comment: Well i tried this what i have in the picture.

area being equal to the Length* Width - 150 = max.......
W+(w-10)+h+h+(h-15) = 75

Comment: @user199167 Do not deface your question.

Comment: deface? sorry, im a first time poster. I just wanted people to know i got.

Comment: accept an answer then @user199167. don't remove content from your question.

Comment: @user199167 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should

Comment: @user199167 You can also leave comments below answers to your question, Please leave the question as it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The two equations you wrote down in your figure are

$$2w+2h-25=75$$
and
$$wh-150=\text{max}$$

where I've taken the first step in simplifying the first equation.  Now *solve* it for one variable in terms of the other, substitute the result into the second equation so that you have a function of one variable that you're seeking to maximize, and then use calculus.

**An alternative hint**:  Imagine you've got $100$ feet of fence, but you've got to surround the dog house as well as the yard.

Answer (score 0):

If a the perimeter of a rectangle is fixed, the area is the most when length and breadth are equal (a square). So, length=breadth=75/4=18.75 As the doghouse fits in the yard, this is the answer.

Comment: This is not correct because the walls of the doghouse make part of the perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Perimeter of yard: $w+h+w-10+h-25=75$

$w+h=50$; $h=50-w$

**Area of yard:** $wh-150$ $\rightarrow$max

$w(50-w)-150$

$50w-w^2-150$

$-(w^2-50w+25^2)+25^2-150$

Area=$-(w-25)^2+475$ $\rightarrow$max when the bracket becomes $0$ i.e. $w=25$

$w+h=50$ $\rightarrow$ $25+h=50$; $h=25$

Therefore, for $Area_{max}$, $w=h=25$

Comment: where did you get the 25^2? were you trying to make a perfect square?

Comment: I used $25^2$ to complete the square for w it made that bracket whole square of $(w-25)$

Comment: as I added $25^2$ in the bracket i actually subtracted it from the whole equation because of negative sign on bracket so in order to balance the equation i added another $25^2$ on the outside

Comment: the equation is maximum when the stuff in the bracket is minimum i.e. 0 so i simply put w-25=0